# SignalR with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

The requirement in our project is, Web UI(MVC 5) will place a request to adapter(intermediate layer) which takes 3-4mins to process the request and computes response.  This response needs to be pushed back to UI. We are planning to implement Signalr for posting back the response to UI. I did a small POC on SignalR to open connection and to call a method from javascript and get response back. how can I push the data from server to client(once connection is set), no call from javascript/Web for requesting the response?.

Answer (score 0):

To push datas from the server to the client the basic usage is :

On the client side :

```
var myHub = $.connection.CustomHub;
myHub.client.myFunction= function (param) {
        alert(param);
};
```

On the server side  :

```
 Clients.All.myFunction("parameter");
```

To find more infos about signalr take a look here :

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

You can download the light chat project in the page it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get Hubcontext of the application

   IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext('HubName');
2. On top of hubcontext can broadcast message to all the clients or groups or to specific client based on connection Id

   hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).JavaScript function(data)